# Jenkins Thin backup failure due to hudson permission issue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins-2.121.1 on docker and I am trying to implement the backup mechanism using Thin backup plugin. After done proper setup and triggered the job, I am able to see backup is failing due to Hudson permission issue where I do have enough permission on the backup directory.

As it shows the permission issue, I have provided the 777 permission for testing, but no luck.  My configurations are below.

```
Backup directory - /var/server/config/jenkins-backup
Backup schedule for full backups - 0 1 * * *
Backup schedule for differential backups - 0 15 * * *
Max number of backup sets - 3
```

My expected result is the backup should happen as per mentioned time but the scheduled job is triggering and failing to do the backup.

Can anyone suggest?

Comment: Seems like permission issue is coming from parent dir of your backup directory. Try by creating backup directory in /tmp folder once.

Comment: I will try this and confirm, but not sure this will work as the command "touch /var/server/config/jenkins-backup/sample.txt" worked from the Jenkins user where i am trying to do the backup operation.

Comment: Have you tried manually by becoming Jenkins user on server  or by creating test job? If not can you try by creating a test job and check if you are able to execute touch cmd from there.

Comment: When I set it to /tmp/jenkins-backup path, then I am able to.  Thanks for this.  As suggested, have created a job under a master and touch command is failing from Jenkins with same Jenkins user but the same working on the physical server.  Am i missing anything?

Comment: Can you execute "id -a" cmd also from Jenkins test job as well as manually from machine. If there is diffrence in output, then first explanation is you have added some group for Jenkins user after starting the jenkins and that group is not included for Jenkins user. In this case restarting jenkins from new cmd prompat will resolve the issue. If this is not the case, then please share more details.

Comment: You are right.  I could see the difference of uid, gid between the Jenkins user from portal and Jenkins user from the server.  I guess this is due to the credential i sent it in the server.  However no help after restarting the Jenkins, still seeing the same level of uid, gid and permission error during backup movement.

Comment: Are you using mounted dir Or using docker jenkins with mounted dir?

Comment: It's not mounted dir and I am using docker Jenkins where by default the user id will create with 1000 uid level which cannot write in other directories.  Is it good if we create the backup directory under the jenkins root directory?  I don't think so. :)

Comment: While starting docker container i think you have given --mount or -v option to mount the volume from your host machine and now user in container and on host is having uid conflict. https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/83ce6f6070f1670563a00d0f61d04edd62b78f4f/Dockerfile#L8 in this link they have given instruction regarding uid. --> # Jenkins is run with user `jenkins`, uid = 1000
# If you bind mount a volume from the host or a data container, 
# ensure you use the same uid

Comment: Thanks, @RohitJindal - Let me explore this

Comment: Great @NGBeginner. Let me know if it works for you or still you have issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether ownership is provided with jenkins user and group

You need to change ownership of `/var/server/config/jenkins-backup`:

```
chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/server/config/jenkins-backup
```